# Which support gems affect the Arc skill?

Tags: path-of-exile

I find I quite like the witch's new (to me) Arc skill, to my regret, however, I discovered that Lesser Multiple Projectiles does not work with it. Which support gems, especially of the projectile modifying sort, DO work with Arc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones that I have used, and can confirm work with Arc, are

```
Blood Magic
Faster Casting
Lightning Penetration
Reduced Mana Cost
```

List of support gems can be found [here](http://www.pathofexile.com/skills/supportgems).

Any others may work, but I have not tested personally, therefore would be total speculation, on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Arc is not a *projectile*, so *Multiple Projectiles* won't do anything.  *Chain* does work though and causes it to chain to more enemies.